# S is a set of three words: “At” “Bat” and “Cat”. For each word w in S, f w( ) is defined as the number of letters in w. What is the range of f?

Tags: functions, lagrange-multiplier

S is a set of three words: “At” “Bat” and “Cat”. For each word w in S, f w( )
is defined as the
number of letters in w. What is the range of f?

Comment: Do you know what the question means?  What exactly is your difficulty?

Comment: not sure how to solve the question and find the range of f?

Comment: What part of the question do you understand?

Comment: none of it need someone to explain it to me would be greatful?

Comment: I find that hard to believe.  You don't know what a function is?  You don't know what "range" means?  You don't know how many letters there are in the word "cat"?

Comment: the answer that i have come up with is. {2} {3} {3} is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you should have put what you have come up with in the body of your question originally, instead of making me drag it out of you.

The range is the set of values assumed by the function.  The function assumes the values $2$ and $3$, so the range is $\{2,3\}.$

The answer you gave,$\{2\}\{3\}\{3\},$ is not standard mathematical notation for anything that I know of.  It looks to me as though you have the general idea, but are weak on how to write it mathematically.  Correct notation is more important than you might think; it's how we communicate with each other.